# Install Informatica PowerCentre 10.4 PostgreSQL

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I would be grateful for your advices regarding the following:
I have PostgeSQL 13, WindowsServer 2016 and would like to use PostgreSQL as a database for Informatica Repository.
I have created user and database in PostgreSQL, opened port 5432 on firewall, but Informatica Pre-installation system check can not connect to PostgreSQL(please see settings in the attached picture)[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBfNF.png)

Thank you in advance for your answers

The adventures are going further.
I was able to install Informatica,but now when I try to create a Repository Service, it fails with message "Error occured loading library pmpostgresql.dll". System error encountered is 126

Comment: First pls ensure you are giving correct parameters - for example, INFRA_USER is a database or an user ? If you setup schema pls mentiion schema too. If all parameters are fine and still same issue then, could you pls try this conn string - `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name`.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for suggestion. Seems, issue is with password encoding settings. Informatica expects password is hashed with MD5